# Enum vs String Literal Best Practices

Tags: javascript, typescript

This question is about best practices when it comes to using enums instead of string literals.

I have the following interface, and I am refactoring the string literals of the "type" property to an enum for more DRY code.

```
export interface AppController {
 restart: (
    type: "end" | "exit,
    id: string,
    continueAt?: number
  ) => void;
}
```

My enum then is:

```
export enum AppRestartTypes {
  END = "end",
  EXIT = "exit",
}
```

My refactored interface now is:

```
export interface AppController {
 restart: (
    type: AppRestartTypes.END | AppRestartTypes.EXIT,
    id: string,
    continueAt?: number
  ) => void;
}
```

Notice that the OR is still present. Is it standard to use only the enum? See below:

```
export interface AppController {
 restart: (
    type: AppRestartTypes,
    id: string,
    continueAt?: number
  ) => void;
}
```

In my mind thats fine, but what if the enum had three properties in it (not just two), but "type" can only be two of them?

Thank you

Comment: If the enum has three values and that field can only be two of them, then typing it as the entire enum would be a code smell.

Comment: thats how it seems to me too. so if i know for sure it will only have two, typing it as the enum is probably desired then? just because its less

Comment: As I previously mentioned, I would argue against that.  Typing it as the whole thing, if it can only be two of the things, makes the validations that typescript performs for you not mesh with what the actual data should be.  It's not really a concern that you could type less or not.  Your data model needs to be accurate.